# Calculate difference in date between rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table where I would like to flag entries that are within 90 days of a prior entry for a given group id.  Context is that these are buy signals for trades.  So I don't want duplicates within a 90 day window, since I am assuming I hold the position for 90 days, and thus would already have bought a position (and I don't want to restart the clock).

So I have:

```
library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-02-15")))
> dt
   id       date
1:  A 2017-01-01
2:  A 2017-02-01
3:  A 2017-05-01
4:  B 2017-01-01
5:  B 2017-05-01
6:  B 2017-10-01
7:  C 2017-01-01
8:  C 2017-02-01
9:  C 2017-02-15
```

And I want to get:

```
> dt2
   id       date with.90d
1:  A 2017-01-01    FALSE
2:  A 2017-02-01     TRUE
3:  A 2017-05-01    FALSE
4:  B 2017-01-01    FALSE
5:  B 2017-05-01    FALSE
6:  B 2017-10-01    FALSE
7:  C 2017-01-01    FALSE
8:  C 2017-02-01     TRUE
9:  C 2017-02-15     TRUE
```

I feel like I should be able to do this with .SD, but I can't quite figure it out.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is difference between `2017-02-01` and `2017-05-01` 89 or 90 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101492/calculate-difference-in-date-between-rows#comment83181026_48101609):

> From first observation X in each group, I want to flag any other observations less than 90 days away from X. Then for the next day observation that is greater than 90 days away from X, call it observation Y, I want to flag any observations within 90 days of Y. Repeat.

If I understood correctly from the expected result, a value of `FALSE` in the `with.90d` column indicates the beginn of 90 day period.

Unfortunately, the beginn of the *next* 90 day period depends on the date of the next observation after expiration of the previous 90 day period. Therefore, we cannot use fixed 90 day intervals starting with the first date in each group.

I have tried to find solutions using *non-equi joins* or *rolling joins* but I ended up so far with a recursive approach:

```
dt3[, with.90d := NA]
while (dt3[, any(is.na(with.90d))]) 
  dt3[is.na(with.90d), cd := date - min(date), by = id][
    is.na(with.90d) & cd == 0, with.90d := FALSE][
      is.na(with.90d) & cd <= 90, with.90d := TRUE]
dt3
```

> ```
>     id       date with.90d      cd
>  1:  A 2017-01-01    FALSE  0 days
>  2:  A 2017-02-01     TRUE 31 days
>  3:  A 2017-05-01    FALSE  0 days
>  4:  B 2017-01-01    FALSE  0 days
>  5:  B 2017-05-01    FALSE  0 days
>  6:  B 2017-10-01    FALSE  0 days
>  7:  C 2017-01-01    FALSE  0 days
>  8:  C 2017-02-01     TRUE 31 days
>  9:  C 2017-02-15     TRUE 45 days
> 10:  D 2017-03-01    FALSE  0 days
> 11:  D 2017-04-01     TRUE 31 days
> 12:  D 2017-05-01     TRUE 61 days
> 13:  D 2017-06-01    FALSE  0 days
> 14:  D 2017-07-01     TRUE 30 days
> 15:  D 2017-08-01     TRUE 61 days
> 16:  E 2017-01-01    FALSE  0 days
> 17:  E 2017-02-01     TRUE 31 days
> 18:  E 2017-03-01     TRUE 59 days
> 19:  E 2017-04-01     TRUE 90 days
> 20:  E 2017-05-01    FALSE  0 days
> 21:  E 2017-06-01     TRUE 31 days
>     id       date with.90d      cd
> ```

Note that I have appended two more groups, `D` and `E` to OP's sample dataset in order to better verify the approach. Also note how the result differs for group `D` which starts on `2017-03-01` and `E` which starts on `2017-01-01`.

#### Explanation

As long as there are `NA` values in `with.90d`, the following sequence is repeated *for the `NA` rows only* (rows with `TRUE` or `FALSE` values are completed):

- Compute the day differences to the first date in each group. Note that  `min(date)` is used which works also with an unordered dataset. Alternatively, `setorder(dt3, date)` and `first(date)` (or `date[1]`) can be used.
- Rows with a day difference of `0` indicate the start of a new period and are flagged as `FALSE`.
- Rows with a day difference of less or equal 90 days are flagged as `TRUE`.
- All other rows remain untouched, i.e., they keep the `NA` value.

For illustration I have kept the helper column `cd`. It can be removed by `dt3[, cd := NULL]`.

#### Data

```
# OP's sample dataset
dt <- data.table(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
                 date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-02-15")))
# append group D
dt2 <- dt[, .(id = c(id, rep("D", 6)), 
              date = c(date, seq(as.Date("2017-03-01"), length.out = 6, by = "1 month")))]
# append group E
dt3 <- dt2[, .(id = c(id, rep("E", 6)), 
               date = c(date, seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), length.out = 6, by = "1 month")))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `difftime`:

```
# Data
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-02-15")))

# Difference in days    
dt[, with.90d := as.numeric(difftime(date, shift(date), units = "days")) < 90, id]
dt[is.na(with.90d), with.90d := FALSE]

#    id       date with.90d
# 1:  A 2017-01-01    FALSE
# 2:  A 2017-02-01     TRUE
# 3:  A 2017-05-01     TRUE
# 4:  B 2017-01-01    FALSE
# 5:  B 2017-05-01    FALSE
# 6:  B 2017-10-01    FALSE
# 7:  C 2017-01-01    FALSE
# 8:  C 2017-02-01     TRUE
# 9:  C 2017-02-15     TRUE
```

Explanation:

- Calculate difference in time using `difftime()`. Difference is between date and shifted date calculated by group (`id`).
- Check if difference is less than 90 days.
- Insert `FALSE` for first date per group (`is.na()`)

Comment: Thanks, that is good.  Problem is that for observation 3, I want a FALSE, since 2017-05-01 is more than 90 days from 2017-01-01. So I would have bought in January, held until end of March, and then May 1 would be a new buy signal.

Comment: @richSC for `2017-05-01` you want 90 days window from `2017-02-01` or `2017-01-01`?

Comment: From first observation X in each group, I want to flag any other observations less than 90 days away from X.  Then for the next day observation that is greater than 90 days away from X, call it observation Y, I want to flag any observations within 90 days of Y.  Repeat.  I can do this trough some iterated loops, but was hoping for something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to compare to all prior trades to make sure that the current trade is not within 90 days of ANY of them. To do this you could try:

```
dt[order(id, date), with.90d := sapply(1:(.N), function(i) all(difftime(date[i], date[1:(i-1)], units = "days") < 90) & i != 1L), by = id]

dt
#   id       date with.90d
#1:  A 2017-01-01    FALSE
#2:  A 2017-02-01     TRUE
#3:  A 2017-05-01    FALSE
#4:  B 2017-01-01    FALSE
#5:  B 2017-05-01    FALSE
#6:  B 2017-10-01    FALSE
#7:  C 2017-01-01    FALSE
#8:  C 2017-02-01     TRUE
#9:  C 2017-02-15     TRUE
```

What this is doing is taking the difference of the current date with all prior dates (within that group) and checking that all these differences are < 90 days. If any is >= 90 it will flag it with `FALSE`. Note that I use `all()` to return a logical, but you could use `min()` which would likely be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can Also use base r functions:

```
transform(dt,with.90days=unlist(by(dt$date,dt$id,function(x)c(F,cumsum(as.numeric(diff(x)))<90))))
   id       date with.90days
1:  A 2017-01-01       FALSE
2:  A 2017-02-01        TRUE
3:  A 2017-05-01       FALSE
4:  B 2017-01-01       FALSE
5:  B 2017-05-01       FALSE
6:  B 2017-10-01       FALSE
7:  C 2017-01-01       FALSE
8:  C 2017-02-01        TRUE
9:  C 2017-02-15        TRUE
```